# Is there a way in Python to do calculations on the least significant index for an array of unknown shape?

Tags: python, arrays

I have been trying to develop a bit of code to do a certain calculation for data points within an array and save this to a new array. The data structure has an inter determinate number of dimensions but the final dimension (least significant) is always the one that needs the calculation done to it. The array to save has one less dimension than the original with the same shape for the first n - 1 dimensions. The setup right now is as follows:

```
array = np.load(ARRAY_LOCATION)

r_shape = array.shape[0:-1]

m = mask       #mask is a masking vector of length n_bin
r = np.zeros( r_shape ) #create array of 0s without last index
```

The calculation is simple for the 1D case, as the calculation is only done once (no for loop required). For the 2D case, I opted for something like this:

```
for i in np.arange( array.shape[0] ):
        r[i] = calculate_value( array[i][m == 0] )
```

The 3D case isn't much more involved:

```
for i in np.arange( array.shape[0] ):
    for j in np.arange( array.shape[1] ):
        r[i, j] = calculate_value( array[i][j][m == 0] )
```

However, I need to know how to do this for nD where n is determined when the array is loaded in. Therefore, I don't think my `r[i, j, k, ...]` notation is going to cut it but I don't know of another way I could set those values. In practice, I need my calculations to run over all available indices until 'there isn't anything left'.

Any help would be great :)